# how can I transpose a 2D matrix in place in C?

Tags: c, matrix, transpose

I'm trying to transpose a 2D matrix (10x10) in place:

```
for (a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    for (b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
        tmp = matrix[a][b];
        matrix[b][a] = matrix[a][b];
        matrix[a][b] = tmp;
    }
}
```

If I can increase the starting value 'b' of the inner for statement by `1`, it works fine.

However, when one loop is turned, the value of the variable is set to `0`. It is very natural.

Is there a way to increase the starting value 'b' of the inner `for` loop after running around a loop?

I really want to solve this problem.

Can you use global variables or any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Change `tmp = matrix[a][b];` to `tmp = matrix[b][a];`

Comment: note that this will be cache inefficient. It might be better to use divide and transpose smaller matrices to improve cache locality [A Cache Efficient Matrix Transpose Program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5200338/995714), [How to efficiently transpose a 2D bit matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41778362/995714)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: this fix alone is not sufficient.

Comment: @juyyk: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 9):

Your swapping code is incorrect: you should overwrite the saved value first.

Furthermore, you must stop the inner loop when `b == a`, otherwise the values would be swapped twice, and the transposition would fail.

Here is a corrected version:

```
/* swap values on either side of the first diagonal */
for (a = 1; a < 10; a++) {
    /* stop the inner loop when b == a */
    for (b = 0; b < a; b++) {
        int tmp = matrix[a][b];
        matrix[a][b] = matrix[b][a];
        matrix[b][a] = tmp;
    }
}
```

This simple algorithm is not cache optimal for large matrices, especially for power of 2 sizes. More elaborate algorithms have been developed for [in place matrix transpostion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition).

For example, here is a benchmark for 1024x1024 matrices comparing the naive algorithm with an advanced recursive approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 1024

static int mat[SIZE][SIZE];

void initialize_matrix(int matrix[SIZE][SIZE]) {
    int a, b, x = 0;
    for (a = 0; a < SIZE; a++) {
        for (b = 0; b < SIZE; b++) {
            mat[a][b] = x++;
        }
    }
}

int check_transpose_matrix(int matrix[SIZE][SIZE]) {
    int a, b, x = 0;
    for (a = 0; a < SIZE; a++) {
        for (b = 0; b < SIZE; b++) {
            if (mat[b][a] != x++)
                return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void naive_transpose(int matrix[SIZE][SIZE]) {
    /* swap values on either side of the first diagonal */
    for (int a = 1; a < SIZE; a++) {
        /* stop the inner loop when b == a */
        for (int b = 0; b < a; b++) {
            int tmp = matrix[a][b];
            matrix[a][b] = matrix[b][a];
            matrix[b][a] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

#define THRESHOLD  4

void transpose_tile(int row, int col, int size, int matrix[SIZE][SIZE]) {
    if (size > THRESHOLD) {
        transpose_tile(row, col, size / 2, matrix);
        transpose_tile(row, col + size / 2, size / 2, matrix);
        transpose_tile(row + size / 2, col, size / 2, matrix);
        transpose_tile(row + size / 2, col + size / 2, size / 2, matrix);
    } else {
        for (int a = 0; a < size; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < size; b++) {
                int tmp = matrix[row + a][col + b];
                matrix[row + a][col + b] = matrix[col + b][row + a];
                matrix[col + b][row + a] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void transpose_tile_diag(int pos, int size, int matrix[SIZE][SIZE]) {
    if (size > THRESHOLD) {
        transpose_tile_diag(pos, size / 2, matrix);
        transpose_tile(pos, pos + size / 2, size / 2, matrix);
        transpose_tile_diag(pos + size / 2, size / 2, matrix);
    } else {
        /* swap values on either side of the first diagonal */
        for (int a = 1; a < size; a++) {
            /* stop the inner loop when b == a */
            for (int b = 0; b < a; b++) {
                int tmp = matrix[pos + a][pos + b];
                matrix[pos + a][pos + b] = matrix[pos + b][pos + a];
                matrix[pos + b][pos + a] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void advanced_transpose(int matrix[SIZE][SIZE]) {
    transpose_tile_diag(0, SIZE, matrix);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    clock_t t_min;

    initialize_matrix(mat);
    naive_transpose(mat);
    if (check_transpose_matrix(mat)) {
        printf("naive_transpose failed!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* benchmark naive algorithm */
    t_min = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        clock_t t = clock();
        naive_transpose(mat);
        t = clock() - t;
        if (i == 0 || t_min > t)
            t_min = t;
    }
    printf("naive: %.3fms\n", t_min * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    initialize_matrix(mat);
    advanced_transpose(mat);
    if (check_transpose_matrix(mat)) {
        printf("advanced_transpose failed!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* benchmark advanced algorithm */
    t_min = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        clock_t t = clock();
        advanced_transpose(mat);
        t = clock() - t;
        if (i == 0 || t_min > t)
            t_min = t;
    }
    printf("advanced: %.3fms\n", t_min * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}
```

Output on my 5 year old macbook:

```
naive: 7.299ms
advanced: 1.157ms
```