# Efficient algorithm to add two binary numbers represented spanning multiple unsigned long long ints

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary, bit-manipulation

I want to sum two binary numbers in this particular framework, I will refer to C++ for coding syntax. 64 binary numbers are encoded into a vector of unsigned long long ints.

```
vector<unsigned long long int> a;
```

where the i-th bit of a[j] is equal to the j-th bit of the i-th number, i = 0, ..., 64-1.

Now let us consider two collections of 64-bit numbers

```
vector<unsigned long long int> a, b;
```

I want to sum, by pairs, the 64 numbers encoded in a to the 64 numbers encoded in b at once, with bitwise operations. For instance, I want to sum the 0-th number encoded in a to the 0-th number encoded in b, the 1-th number encoded in a to the 1-th number encoded in b, etc., and write the result into a

```
vector<unsigned long long int> c;
```

Here a simple example:

in base 2, the vectors a, b and c read

```
a: 
[0] = { 0010001010001111100011001100111001010010001101101101011101111001 }
[1] = { 1101110100110001111110010010011111110011001001011011101110000100 }
[2] = { 1010011000001101100010010011010011011100010000010111011101010010 }
[3] = { 0110001101001010111001110000100100010001101100110101101110011111 }

b: 
[0] = { 0001100000011110111101010100111100111101000100101100000101000110 }
[1] = { 1001101111111100000000111001100110100110101000110011111101111011 }
[2] = { 1011101001001111110110010001000000000100010010100011010000001011 }
[3] = { 1100011100011000101111100111001110110111011011000100111000111110 }

c: 
[0] = { 0011101010010001011110011000000101101111001001000001011000111111 }
[1] = { 0100011011000011011111101111000001000101100101000100010110111111 }
[2] = { 1000010101111110110100010010101101101010001010001111100000011001 }
[3] = { 0001111001011111110100000110111000110010100111000010001011100011 }
[4] = { 1110001100001000101011110001000110010101011000110101111100011110 }
```

while in base 10 they read:

```
    a: 
{6 10 13 2 2 6 13 10 1 8 2 2 13 5 9 7 15 10 10 2 7 9 8 14 1 1 6 4 9 7 3 10 6 7 2 15 4 4 3 10 8 4 11 9 0 3 9 14 3 13 6 15 10 5 15 15 10 5 1 13 9 10 12 9 }
    
    b: 
{14 8 4 7 7 8 14 10 2 6 2 11 15 7 5 4 13 5 9 13 12 9 10 7 2 9 8 14 3 1 9 11 10 0 11 9 1 15 10 9 2 12 10 1 12 8 7 2 1 9 6 6 10 14 10 3 0 3 10 10 14 9 15 6 }
    
    c: 
{20 18 17 9 9 14 27 20 3 14 4 13 28 12 14 11 28 15 19 15 19 18 18 21 3 10 14 18 12 8 12 21 16 7 13 24 5 19 13 19 10 16 21 10 12 11 16 16 4 22 12 21 20 19 25 18 10 8 11 23 23 19 27 15 }
```

What is the fastest way to do this? I seem to recall that one had to use a binary-tree structure, but I am not sure.

For you to understand better why I am asking this question: I am doing this because I would like to 'beat' the standard '+' operator of C++. For instance, if I encoded 64 numbers in `a`, 64 numbers in `b` and summed them efficiently with the method above, would this take a time smaller than 64 x [time taken by summing 64 `unsigned long long ints` with the ordinary '+']? I have tried to measure this time, but it is not easy... Do you have an idea on how to measure this ?

Comment: What is `v[j]`? Did you mean `a[j]`? Please edit your post to clarify.

Comment: Please do reword and clarify. It sound like you're saying that `(a[i] >> j) & 0x1` == `(a[j] >> i) & 0x1`, but how does this relate to the summation later? Are you looking for an evil bit-twiddling trick you can take advantage of while summing to reduce the work of the summing?

Comment: The most efficient method is to use integral types that can hold the values, for example, 128-bit or 256-bit integers.  Otherwise, you have to use the standard technique of adding `a` + `b` + `carry`.  This may be easier using assembly language.

Comment: `where the i-th bit of v[j] is equal to the j-th bit of the i-th number, i = 0, ..., 64-1.` - can you elaborate what you mean by this?

Comment: What would make your issue easier to understand is to share a sample input set for `a` and `b` and show the expected `c` result.

Comment: @James Re "with bitwise operations" So the use of `+` is disallowed? How about `<`? If both `+` and `<` are allowed, a solution is straightforward.

Comment: Standard technique of a + b + carry should work great.  You'll effectively have 64-wide SIMD working on all 64 numbers at once, but only one bit in each number.

Comment: Your question requires a minimal reproducible example. That would make it more clear how your numbers are stored than your attempts at describing it in plain English.

Comment: Do you have an algorithm for adding two integers bit-by-bit? Is there any difficulty expanding that to multiple pairs of integers?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews  thank you for your reply. May you please clarify why using a 128- or 256-bit integral type would speed up the method in the reply by harold ?

Comment: @James, Usually anything implemented in hardware is a lot faster than a software implementation.  The concept can be demonstrated quite easily.  Pick 2 32-bit numbers.  Implement them using `uint8_t` variables.  Note the speed.  Now, use `uint32_t` for the numbers and add them.  Very low level, 32-bit processors have an ALU (Arithmetic Logic Unit), that is set up for 32-bit addition ("adder" circuits that have 32-bit data bus).  Some processors or Systems On a Chip (SOC), also have the capability of hardware addition of 128 or 256 bit integers.

Comment: @James:  If systems need to add larger numbers, they can use a custom FPGA or ASIC, that is specially designed to support large number arithmetic.  I worked at a shop that had a 256-bit barrel shifter, in an FPGA, and other items to support cryptography.  These operations would be very slow if using a software implementation, thus the shop decided to implement tools in an FPGA and finally converted to an ASIC.  FYI, hardware can easily do operations in parallel that software has difficulty with.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews adding transposed numbers should be essentially trivial in hardware, but this isn't really about bigints I'm not sure if you caught that

Answer (score 1):

Pairwise adding a pair of arrays of transposed integers (transposed integer arrays? anyway: a collection of integers with each logical integer physically stored across a column of a bit-matrix) can be done like this:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>

using std::uint64_t;
using std::size_t;

std::vector<uint64_t> add_transposed_integers(
    const std::vector<uint64_t> &a,
    const std::vector<uint64_t> &b)
{
    size_t n = a.size();
    std::vector<uint64_t> c(n + 1);

    uint64_t carry = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        uint64_t sum = (a[i] ^ b[i]) ^ carry;
        carry = (a[i] & b[i]) | (carry & (a[i] ^ b[i]));
        c[i] = sum;
    }
    c[n] = carry;

    return c;
}
```

The bitwise logic here is just ripple carry addition.

I made the assumption that `a` and `b` are supposed to have the same number of bits (which translates to: their vectors all have the same length) and `c` has one more bit. If that's not the case, you can easily make some modifications.

I don't make any claim about this being the fastest possible way, but making it faster is not easy. For example you might think about SIMD, but the carry propagation makes that really weird, you'd need some more advanced addition algorithm such as Kogge-Stone which can support some parallelism, but then it costs a lot more operations in total.

Comment: There seems to be an intent to not limit the number of bits / the length of the vectors. Would you consider, if the final carry is not zero, pushing that onto `c`? That would be a simple way to drop one assumption (simpler than accounting for `a` and `b` being different lengths).

Comment: Sure, that would work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This [solution suggested by Harold](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77971778/13797696) is a very efficient and fast approach for adding many numbers at once (N<=64) without the multi-processing overhead for less than about 256 bit precision (far more than typical). I ran some tests with multithreading only (on a Intel i7-11850H CPU or 16 threads), but I did not use AVX512 instructions. There are many algos out there for [efficiently transposing 2D-bit fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41778468/13797696), but transposing (two number arrays forward and the result back) has some overhead. Without the transposing overhead, the repetitive additions are about 30% faster for a 64x64 matrix, this vanishes as the precision grows to about 256 bits. For repetitive operations with arbitrary accuracy (over 64-bits), there are some [highly optimized libraries](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: Of course, after transposing it's just addition. But transposing the matrix is quite difficult. I have some experience with transposing bit-matrices of [various](https://bitmath.blogspot.com/2023/04/not-transposing-16x16-bitmatrix.html) [dimensions](https://bitmath.blogspot.com/2023/09/permuting-bits-with-gf2p8affineqb.html), it's rough, and that was *with* special operations.

Comment: Transposing an 64x64 matrix already costs 72 AVX512 operations, and we'd have to do it 3 times (for A, B, and the result). But also with AVX512, the plain ripple carry addition only takes 2 `vpternlogq` operations per iteration (sadly using them as scalar operations), that's not even necessarily bad.

Comment: Yes, I am convinced that your method will be faster, even though it seems impossible to parallelize due to the carry, because (1) transposing back and forth for ordinary arithmetic will be very expensive, (2) your method of calculation is probably more efficient than running with 64 threads already. Maybe with a GPU implementation where many computations can take place on 64 cores without the need to transpose over and over will be faster, but I suppose the problem will need at least 10 operations in a row on 64 cores.